# checking repetion of words in list of objects

Tags: vb.net, linq

i have a class `MedicineData`

```
Public Class MedicineDataDB

    Public Sub New(ByVal dtr As DataRow)
        Id = Int32.Parse(dtr("Id"))
        MedicineName = dtr("medicineName").ToString()
        BookName = dtr("book").ToString()
        AuthorName = dtr("author").ToString()
        MedicineData = dtr("newData").ToString()
    End Sub

    Dim _bookName As String
    Dim _authorName As String
    Dim _medicineDataID As Integer
    Dim _medicineName As String
    Dim _medicineData As String
    Public Property Id() As Integer
        Get
            Return _medicineDataID
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _medicineDataID = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property MedicineName() As String
        Get
            Return _medicineName
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _medicineName = value
        End Set
    End Property


    Public Property BookName() As String
        Get
            Return _bookName
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _bookName = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property AuthorName() As String
        Get
            Return _AuthorName
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _AuthorName = value
        End Set
    End Property


    Public Property MedicineData() As String
        Get
            Return _medicineData
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _medicineData = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

and a list of

```
Dim medicineDataList As New List(Of MedicineDataDB)()
```

i need to check the repetitions of a particular word in a property `MedicineData` inside the list.
is there any way to implement this using linq
using vb.net?

Comment: Give it a go.  Intellisense can be incredibly helpful.  First decide what you want - the count of repeats or a subset of the list

Comment: need only one value that is count of repeats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to count the repetition of some text inside each item's property MedecineData you could do

```
Dim countByIds = From m In medicineDataList
                 Select m.Id, Count = SomeMethodWhichCalculateYourCount(m.MedecineData)
```

That way you'll get back an IEnumerable of some anonymous type which will have to properties : Id (the Id of the source item) and the Count following your criteria.
The SomeMethodWhichCalculateYourCount method could be as simple as a direct call to `Length` property (so inlined in the query without actual method) or a custom method you have alongside

Then if you want an overall count you can modify this query or build another one using the first for example :

```
Dim overallCount = Aggregate c In countByIds Into Sum(c.Count)
```

a [fiddle example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RvgPpW)

Comment: have tried this get a error "range variable name can be inferred only from a simple or qualified name with no arguments"
 and it tries to check equal to and returns false does not assign the   value from the function to the  count variable

Comment: @user2617874 make sure you haven't already a "count" variable in scope declared

Comment: @user2617874 I edited my answer to show a fiddle example if you want

Answer (score 1):

LINQ does provide extension methods which allow you to do that.  For instance, you could use the [`Where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803(v=vs.110).aspx) method to filter the list down to just the items that match, then you could use the [`Count`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338038(v=vs.110).aspx) method to get the number of them:

```
Dim count As Integer = medicineDataList.Where(Function(x) x.MedicineData = "Some Value").Count
```

Technically, LINQ's `Count` extension method allows you to give it a predicate, you don't really need the call to `Where`, however, since `List` implements its own `Count` property, that hides the extension method.  So, to do it with the single `Count` method, you'd have to first cast it to `IEnumerable(Of T)`, like this:

```
Dim count As Integer = DirectCast(medicineDataList, MedicineDataDB).Count(Function(x) x.MedicineData = "Some Value")
```

But it's actually easier to just call `Where`.

Comment: the problem list is that the medcineData property is a not only that a few words it is a  text data.

if i use it this way ;
dim count as integer=medicineDatalist.where(function(x) x.MedicineData.contains("some value")).count

 will it  return the number of time "some value" is repeated in medicineDataList?

Comment: So then change the test in the predicate.  For instance, use `String.Contains` (e.g. `Function(x) x.MedicineData.Contains("Some Value")` ).

Comment: can i  create a method in that object and call it inside the linq?

Comment: Yes you can do that.  The predicate being passed to LINQ, in my examples, are single-line lambda expressions.  You can do anything you want in the predicate.  You could give it a multi-line lambda or even a delegate to any method that matches the predicate's signature.